# c++ Libraries for windows only

Tags: c++, libraries

here is a list with c++ headers.
I would like to know if they can be used to compile programs only for windows or for other systems too:

```
iostream or iostream.h
stdio.h
cstdlib
math.h
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote? That's a valid and well answerable question.

Comment: what are you asking? - are these header files os-independent?

Answer (score 4):

Almost all those library headers may be used to compile for any operating system, they are maintained by ISO C++, a standardization committee.

https://isocpp.org/faq

Note however the exception is `iostream.h`. It won't compile for most modern compilers as it is part of a pre standard (the standard being what is defined by the ISO committee).

Just use

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead.

Comment: `iostream.h` isn't standard!

Comment: No it wasn't ever an established standard. There wasn't any before C++98. I'm suspecting you are studying in India. Unfortunately Turbo C++ is used a lot at schools/universities there AFAIK from the questions coming up here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Fortunately I'm using GCC.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't downvote your answer because of my previous statement, someone else did. I don't think your answer is that bad to deserve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile standard C++ compliant code for almost any system, no matter of windows, linux, iOs, etc.

> `iostream or iostream.h`

`iostream.h` is not a standard library header. It was used by ancient compilers (e.g. Turbo C++), before any c++ standard was established. These were only available for old windows/DOS systems IIRC.

> `stdio.h`
>   `math.h`

These refer to the c library, and can be used in standard c++

> `cstdlib`

This is the c++ wrapper for the corresponding c library header `stdlib.h` available in the current standard.

Comment: How is this answer answering ; "I would like to know if they can be used to compile programs only for windows or for other systems too"

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal So standard c++ compliant programs can be compiled for any systems? Is this clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

The files you listed are not libraries, but header files.

They are part of the standard C++ (for `iostream`) and C (for `math.h` `stdio.h`) libraries. Every compiler that is conformant to those standards has to have these headers for you to use.

To clarify: You cannot copy those files from your compiler on Windows and use them on another platform, but your program is free to use them, because the compiler has to provide them.